# How to set marker in center position in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When i click the text. google map will draw on modal pop up in bootstrap

Here google map is created and location is point out by marker. marker placed in left top corner. not in center position.

Calling the google map

```
td_location.innerHTML = '<span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map"><img src="img/marker.png" class="add_marker" onclick="createMap('+json_obj.devices[i].latitude+','+json_obj.devices[i].longitude+')"/></span>'
```

google map creation

```
function createMap(lat,lng)
    {
        var mapOptions={
            zoom:10,
            //center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        };
       map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locationMap'),mapOptions);
         var pos=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          map: map,
         });

         map.setCenter(pos);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150409/google-map-v3-set-center-to-specific-marker

Comment: Is this about infoWindow of Google Maps?  I don't see any infoWindow code in your question?

Comment: I didn't use infowindow. I get a address and show in table. and I got answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(pos);
    });
```