# Google Maps Api - center around marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to center the map around the marker, right now you can barely see the marker in the left corner.

My code is:

```
 <script>
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $hotelInformation['latitude']?>, <?php echo $hotelInformation['longitude']?>);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,          
        zoom: 12,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"<?php echo $hotelInformation['name']?>"
      });
    var latLng = marker.getPosition(); 
    map.setCenter(latLng);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Have tried in multiple ways to get it to center but it doesen't work out
How do I center the map so the marker is in the middle?

Comment: did you google first, this is a duplicate of so many http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150409/google-map-v3-set-center-to-specific-marker ... = map.setCenter();

Comment: @Mayhem, I have tried from your suggested link and tried google it , going through the google map api. But still I can't seem to get it to work. I have updated my code in the top - can you spot what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code looks to be correct, check your browser console for any errors..

Comment: There is [nothing wrong with the posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/abrvj4zs/) (except that it doesn't provide a real latitude or longitude).  What does your HTML/CSS look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following code on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_first

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>


window.initialize = function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.0000,138.0000);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,          
        zoom: 12,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"123"
      });
    var latLng = marker.getPosition(); 
    map.setCenter(latLng);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The reason why i suggest w3school, well jsfiddle was being a pain in the .... to get gmaps working.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create the `latLng` variable, you already know the position, just use `map.setCenter(myLatlng);`

Comment: This is a copy of his code, just a online example using it.. well minus the have to copy n paste to w3

Comment: ... so does it answer his question?